# Update list with positive elements

Tags: algorithm, scala

Update list with negative elements.
For example init:

```
List(1,-2,-3)
```

final:

```
List(1,2,3)
```

Scala solution:

```
def fpUpdateList(el: List[Int]): List[Int] = el.map(e => if (e < 0) e - e * 2; else e)
```

Comment: I don't think your solution will work for numbers lower then `Int.MinValue / 2`

Comment: It's not clear what transformation you're expecting, or why you don't use simply `-e`. Please clarify

Comment: Note that `fpUpdateList` doesn't actually `update`, i.e. change/modify the input `el: List[Int]` - it creates a new one.

Comment: Is this answered?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a question or what, but here's a more concise way:

```
def fpUpdateList(el: List[Int]) = el.map(Math.abs)
```